# Where are the MX (Mail Exchange) records held?

Tags: domain

Are MX (Mail Exchange) records for a domain a held at domain host or at the Internet Service
Provider

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are set and transfered from your domain's start of authority. That may be your domain host or registrar's nameservers, or any nameserver defined as start of authority for your domain.

Answer (score 1):

At the domain host (which is usually your registrar).